# Numpy aggregate within zones

Tags: python, numpy, netcdf

Is there a way to do a zonal stat function on two netcdf files in python using numpy? But without using gdal? The finer resolution netcdf is 0.5 degree and the larger netcdf is 2 degree. So, I want to average all the 0.5 degree cells falling within the larger 2 degree cell.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than using numpy I would actually perform this task using climate data operators (cdo).  This can handle all types of native grid, not just the special case you have here where one gridcell divides exactly into 16.

To map file1.nc to file2.nc, we first calculate the weights.

```
cdo gencon,file2.nc file1.nc weights.nc
```

Here I am using 1st order conservative remapping, so assuming file1 is the 0.5 resolution and file2 is 2.0, the total over the coarse area should be conserved.  Note there are many other options in cdo for remapping.

Now we remap:

```
cdo remap,file2.nc,weights.nc file1.nc file1_remap.nc
```

Making differences and zonal means is also simple:

```
cdo sub file1_remap.nc file2.nc diff.nc
cdo zonmean diff.nc diff_zonmean.nc
```

you can even use pipe to keep it on one line:

```
cdo zonmean -sub file1_remap.nc file2.nc diff_zonmean.nc
```